# Returning non-garbage values in char* from C function to python in Swig

Tags: python, c, swig

I'm trying to use a `C` function from a `python` script. This function returns an array `char*`.
The function looks like:

```
char* getData(char* id) {
    char* old_place = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    if (modifyArr(id,old_place) == 0) {
        return old_place;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

In Python I have:

```
old = Data.getData(id)
```

And I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

That's because `old_place` does not use all of its `256` chars and then I have garbage values which passed. How can I return only the non-garbage values?

**Edit**: About the string terminator (`'\0'`), In the `modifyArr` I change `old_place` like this:

```
sscanf(line," %s ",old_place);
```

I read the lines of a file and the needed one I insert into `old_place` so I'm not sure how to add the string terminator.

Comment: Are you working with strings? Do you remember to add the string terminator?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for mentioned "string terminator". please see my edit.

Comment: what does `modifyArr` do?  don't you still have a memory leak?

Comment: @MFisherKDX In the Data.i file I use `%newobject getData` so I don't think I have. `modifyArr` just gets the needed line from a file and inserted in that array.

Comment: if your function returns NULL, how do you release the allocated value `old_place`?

Comment: @MFisherKDX Acatully I'm now sure. I though Swig does it for me because of using `%newobject getData`.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `bzero` to `old_place`:

```
char* getData(char* id) {
    char* old_place = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    bzero(old_place, 256);
    if (modifyArr(id,old_place) == 0) {
        return old_place;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

`bzero` sets to `\0` `n` bytes of `char*` that you pass in it.
So this way you erase all garbage values in `char*` that you `malloc`.

See reference regarding this function:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html

**EDIT**:

Updating answer according to comments, thanks to [MFisherKDX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8767209/mfisherkdx)

Alternatively and more properly is applying `memset` to `old_place`:

```
char* getData(char* id) {
    char* old_place = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    memset(old_place, 0, 256);
    if (modifyArr(id,old_place) == 0) {
        return old_place;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

`memset` sets first `n` bytes of `char*` that you pass in it with a `char` which number in ASCII table you pass as 2nd parameter.
In your case use 0 (which is `\0`) as `char` to write in `char*`.

Reference to `memset`: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm

**EDIT 2**: Ok, fair enough, `calloc` is simpler than above manipulations.
Just replace `malloc` on `calloc` in your function:

```
char* getData(char* id) {
    char* old_place = calloc(256, sizeof(char));
    if (modifyArr(id,old_place) == 0) {
        return old_place;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

`calloc` does the same as `malloc` and writes `\0` to all allocated bytes.

Comment: `bzero`? What's that from?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I added a reference regarding it

Comment: @MFisherKDX I was already writing an update regarding `memset` as an alternative and more generalized approach=) but thanks anyway, I didn't know that `bzero` is deprecated.

Comment: By the way, @DmitriyFialkovskiy why using `malloc + memset(..., 0)` when there's `calloc()` that does exactly this? Simpler, no?

Comment: `calloc` has two parameters that get multiplied together. So use `calloc(256, 1)` or `calloc(256, sizeof(char))` or `calloc(256, sizeof(*old_place))`.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Modify the C function so that it actually only returns the "useful" data, resizing the array and making it a valid UTF-8 string.
2. Use `ctypes.c_char_p` to cast the result of the call in Python.

What you actually need obviously depends on the specific scenario.

---

Method 1 could be done like this, if you are working with ASCII values:

```
char* getData(char* id) {
    char* old_place = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
    size_t i;

    if (modifyArr(id, old_place) == 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < 256-1; i++) {
            if (old_place[i] > 127)
                break; // Stop at the first non-ASCII value.
        }

        old_place[i] = '\0'; // Correctly terminate the string.

        return old_place;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

This will generate a valid string and you'll be able to work with it in Python.

---

Method 2 could be done like this:

```
import ctypes

mylib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./mylib.so')

data_id = "something"
data = (ctypes.c_char_p)(mylib.getData(data_id))

# data.value is now a bytes() object
print(data.value)
```

Output:

```
b'abcdwhatever\xfd\x8a\xc5\x7f...'
```

Comment: Can you explain about the first solution please?

Comment: @vesii added method 1 too.